# Can't link to a stylesheet or a script in HTML served by Express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm trying to split up the code for my Express app into multiple files. However, I can't use `<link href>` or `<script src>` to link to stylesheets or scripts.

Here is the relevant code from my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

My file structure is:

```
.
├── index.js
└── public
    ├── favicon.ico
    └── index.html
```

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Your express program only serves `public/index.html`. You don't have any code to serve stylesheets or scripts.

Comment: @Quentin Can you serve a stylesheet with res.sendFile?

Comment: Yes. It's a bad idea, but you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have :

> ```
> app.get('/', (req, res) => {
>   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
> });
> ```

So when the browser asks for `/` you'll send it `index.html`.

That is **all** you have.

If the browser asks for **anything** else you'll sent it a 404 error page.

If you want to serve static files, then use the `static` module (and that includes for the *index.html* file you are serving up with an explicit route).

This is covered in the [getting started guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)!

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```